# Is there a way to order posts in a category with a button? [Wordpress]

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I wish to put a drop-down button on my WordPress category page. This drop-down button will have two choices; 'Ascending' and 'Descending'. After clicking the choice, posts on that page will re-order accordingly.

Can anyone help? Right now, the theme is using years. But it doesn't work properly.

Below, the theme is displaying post years in a drop-down menü.

```
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Sırala</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <?php 
                                                $terms_year = array(
                                                    'post_type'         => array('post'),
                                                );
                                                $years = array();
                                                $query_year = new WP_Query( $terms_year );
                                                if ( $query_year->have_posts() ) :
                                                    while ( $query_year->have_posts() ) : $query_year->the_post();
                                                        $year = get_the_date('Y');
                                                        if(!in_array($year, $years)){
                                                            $years[] = $year;
                                                        }
                                                    endwhile;
                                                    wp_reset_postdata();
                                                endif;
                                                foreach ($years as $year) {
                                            ?>
                                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#year-<?php echo $year; ?>" type="button" role="tab"><?php echo $year; ?></a></li>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
```

I want to change that, as I have mentioned.

And here is how posts are displayed (but it doesn't work).

```
<?php                        
                        foreach( $years as $year ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="year-<?php echo $year; ?>">
                        <div class="items">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <?php wp_reset_query(); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $date = get_the_date('Y'); ?> 
                                    <?php if($date == $year) { ?>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 column">
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: <?php echo $rl_category_color; ?>;" class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                                <div class="in">
                                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between author">
                                                        <div class="author-name col-7">
                                                            <?php 
                                                                $author = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'postAuthor', true );
                                                                if(!empty($author)) {                                                       
                                                                    foreach ($author as $author_item => $item) {
                                                                        echo get_the_title($item).'<br>';
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            ?>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="rank col-5 text-end">
                                                            <?php 
                                                                $konu = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
                                                                foreach ($konu as $item) {
                                                                    $konu_name = $item->name;
                                                                }
                                                                echo $konu_name;
                                                            ?>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="title"><?php echo title_limit(40); ?></div>
                                                    <p><?php echo icerik_limit(get_the_content(), 150); ?></p>                                              
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Related Page: https://www.mgc.com.tr/haberler/

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtXCB.png)

Answer (score 1):

To modify the code and use the Ascending (ASC) and Descending (DESC) order without using the year, you can follow these steps:

1. Add the dropdown form to your template file:

```
<form id="sorting-dropdown" method="get">
    <select name="order" id="order" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Sort By</option>
        <option value="ASC" <?php echo $order === 'ASC' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Ascending</option>
        <option value="DESC" <?php echo $order === 'DESC' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Descending</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

2. Modify the template file to include the 'order' parameter and update the WP_Query:

```
<?php
// Get the 'order' parameter from the URL
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'DESC';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // Change this to your custom post type if necessary
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date', // Change this to the field you want to sort by
    'order' => $order
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Your post template code here
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'No posts found';
}
?>
```

Replace the **wp_reset_query();** line with the **$args** array and new WP_Query provided above. Additionally, replace the inner **if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();** loop with the **if ($query->have_posts()) {** loop.

Now, when a user selects 'Ascending' or 'Descending' from the dropdown, the page will reload, and the posts will be displayed in the chosen order.